# XML System.InvalidOperationException: Duplicate attribute

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

The idea is that I need to return a list of Announcements and a list of videos as a string from my web service.  I'm having problems putting the lists into the XML Schema.

Here's my XML schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="WelcomeScreenSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:int"/>
  <xs:attribute name="Added" type="xs:dateTime"/>

  <xs:element name="WelcomeScreen">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element ref="Announcements" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element ref="Videos" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" />
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="Announcements">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Announcement" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="Videos">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Video" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="Announcement">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute ref="ID" use="required"/>
      <xs:attribute ref="Added" use="required"/>
      <xs:attribute name="HTML" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="Video">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute ref="ID" use="required"/>
      <xs:attribute ref="Added" use="required"/>
      <xs:attribute name="URL" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
      <xs:attribute name="Title" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
      <xs:attribute name="Description" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I'm populating my data using the following C#:

```
XmlObject result = new XmlObject("C:\path\to\schema.xsd");

result.Add(new XElement("WelcomeScreen"));
result.Root.Add(new XElement("Announcements"));
result.Root.Add(new XElement("Videos"));

result.Root.Element("Announcements").Add(new XElement("Announcement",
    new XAttribute("ID", Convert.ToString(id)),
    new XAttribute("HTML", html),
    new XAttribute("Added", added)
));

result.Root.Element("Videos").Add(new XElement("Video",
    new XAttribute("ID", Convert.ToString(id)),
    new XAttribute("HTML", URL),
    new XAttribute("HTML", Title),
    new XAttribute("HTML", Description),
    new XAttribute("Added", added)
));
```

The lines where I add the `Announcement` and `Video` elements, are actually inside loops where I'm reading info from my database, but I excluded that code for brevity.

It loads three `Announcement` elements into the schema without a problem.  When it tries to load the first `Video` element, it crashes giving the following error:

```
System.Exception was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Error getting Welcome Screen info from DB. : System.InvalidOperationException: Duplicate attribute.
   at System.Xml.Linq.XElement.AddAttributeSkipNotify(XAttribute a)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddContentSkipNotify(Object content)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddContentSkipNotify(Object content)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the same attribute multiple times, which is not allowed

```
result.Root.Element("Videos").Add(new XElement("Video",
new XAttribute("ID", Convert.ToString(id)),
new XAttribute("HTML", URL),
new XAttribute("HTML", Title),
new XAttribute("HTML", Description),
new XAttribute("Added", added)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to add three `HTML` attributes in `Video`. I think it should be:

```
result.Root.Element("Videos").Add(new XElement("Video",
    new XAttribute("ID", Convert.ToString(id)),
    new XAttribute("URL", URL),
    new XAttribute("Title", Title),
    new XAttribute("Description", Description),
    new XAttribute("Added", added)
));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think these attribute should have different name each of them and that's why it's complaining duplicate attribute...

```
new XAttribute("HTML", URL),
new XAttribute("HTML", Title),
new XAttribute("HTML", Description),
```

You probably want to write like this

```
new XAttribute("URL", URL),
new XAttribute("Title", Title),
new XAttribute("Description", Description),
```